# How to print the current row number when using .apply on DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I've seen this question for R, but not for python.

Basically, I have a large DataFrame where I apply a function row-wise. It takes a very long time to run and I hoped to put a print statement to show where I am. I put together an example of what I would like to do.

I know an alternative, but I wondered if possible with apply.

So this would work fine

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1:[2,3,4], 2: [0,0,0]})

i = 0
for rows in df:
    print ("Current row: {}".format(i))
    df[2][i] = df[0][i] * df[1][i] 
    i += 1

print (df)
```

Output

```
Current row: 0
Current row: 1
Current row: 2

    0   1   2
0   1   2   2
1   2   3   6
2   3   4   12
```

But I hoped to do something with apply such as:

```
def func(df):
    #something here to print
    return df[0] * df[1]

df[2] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it using that way, you described? What was the outcome?

Comment: Actually just tried something with iloc and it works. So i did:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1:[2,3,4], 2: [0,0,0]})

def func(df):
    print (df.iloc[0])
    return df[0] * df[1]

df[2] = df.apply(func,axis=1)

Comment: Why don't you just use df[2]=df[0] * df[1]. Any specific reason to do it through a loop? this way it will be quicker.

Comment: Hi Sal, Thank you for your comment. This is just a quick example but the actual function that I wanted to use it for is a lot more complex. I appreciate the suggestion in any case. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can write your function like this:

```
def func(df):
    print(f'Current row: {df.name}')
    return df[0] * df[1]
```

The usage is following:

```
>>> df[2] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
Current row: 0
Current row: 1
Current row: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`series.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html):

```
>>> def mul(row):
        print('Current row:', row.name)
        return row[0] * row[1]

>>> df[2] = df.apply(mul, axis=1);print(df)

Current row: 0
Current row: 1
Current row: 2
   0  1   2
0  1  2   2
1  2  3   6
2  3  4  12
```